# How to loop a kaplan-meier command in spss syntax?

Tags: loops, spss

I'm working in SPSS with this kaplan-meier command:

```
KM data BY sample
  /STATUS=status(0)
  /PRINT TABLE MEAN
  /PLOT SURVIVAL HAZARD
  /TEST LOGRANK BRESLOW TARONE
  /COMPARE OVERALL POOLED.
```

This is no problem but there's a lot of data i have to process and I'm trying to get this in a syntax file together. Can i do a loop of several kaplan-meier commands with data going through a set of variables such as {time0 time1 time2} and sample going through a set such as {sample0 sample1 sample2}.

I tried with DO REPEAT - END REPEAT. But I couldnt get it to work.

Comment: `DO REPEAT - END REPEAT` is limited to a set of commands. See the syntax reference manual. You can use macro commands or python plugin to achieve looping of `KM`.

Answer (score 1):

DO REPEAT applies to transformation commands.  Procedures cannot be placed inside loops.  However, if you install the Python Essentials from the SPSS Community site (www.ibm.com/developerworks/spssdevcentral), this is easy to do.  If you can provide more details on what you want to loop over, we can explain how to do this.